Data Not Persisting in GridDB After Insert
I’m using the GridDB Python client to insert data into a container, but after inserting the data, I can’t seem to retrieve it. The code executes without any errors, but when I query the container, the inserted data is missing.
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

try:
    # Connect to the GridDB store
    store = factory.get_store(
        notification_member="123.0.0.1",
        notification_port=31999,
        cluster_name="myCluster",
        username="admin",
        password="admin"
    )

    # Retrieve or create the container
    container = store.get_container("personContainer")
    if container is None:
        container_info = griddb.ContainerInfo(
            "personContainer",
            [
                griddb.ColumnInfo("id", griddb.GS_TYPE_INTEGER),
                griddb.ColumnInfo("name", griddb.GS_TYPE_STRING),
                griddb.ColumnInfo("age", griddb.GS_TYPE_INTEGER)
            ],
            griddb.CONTAINER_COLLECTION, True
        )
        container = store.put_container(container_info)

    # Insert data
    row = [1, "John Doe", 30]
    container.put(row)

except griddb.GSException as e:
    for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
        print(f"[{i}] Error code: {e.get_error_code(i)}")
        print(f"Error message: {e.get_message(i)}")

The code runs without any errors, but when I query the container, I cannot find the inserted data. It seems that the data is not being persisted in the container after the put() operation.
What I’ve tried:

Double-checked the GridDB server and confirmed it’s running.
Verified that the container schema is correct and that the container exists.
Looked through the documentation for common issues with put().

Why is the data not being persisted in GridDB after the insert operation, and how can I make sure that the inserted data is saved properly?
